# Python iterator: prev() like there is next()?

Tags: python

Is there a way to do go backwards on an iterator. For example:

```
x = ['a','b','c'] # has __iter__
x_iter = iter(x)  # now has __next__
next(x_iter)
# 'a'
next(x_iter)
# 'b'
prev(x_iter) # what about adding a __prev__ ?
# 'c'
```

Comment: No, there isn't. Iterators don't generally have any memory.

Comment: Are you just curios or do you have something where this would help you?

Comment: The iterator protocol only has a `__next__` and nothing for previous. Of course, you could *implement* this on an object that also implements the Python iterator protocol, but that isn't going to be understood by other Python built-ins or have support built into the language, but nothing is stopping you